# ES6 Spread operator (Rest Parameter) - syntax fails with Safari 9

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

**UPDATE:** FelixKling rightly points out that my use of the term `spread operator` was incorrect and it should be `Rest Parameter`. Using the compatibility table I linked to, it clearly shows that the `Rest Parameter` is not supported in Safari 9. Clarifying that it is a `Rest Parameter` is the real answer to this question (although the example of how to rewrite the function is excellent).

---

I wrote a javascript function performance tester which tests how long a function takes to run. It uses the ES6 spread operator (...) and it works fine in Firefox but not in Safari (up to version 9.1.2). According to this [compatibility chart](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), Safari 9 received a score of 9/15 for the spread operator and I presume this is a shortcoming of Safari 9. Is there an ES6 way to rewrite it so it will work with Safari 9 (and if not, why the "9" in 9/15 - I would think it means that it must have worked in some situations)?

```
function timerTest(func, iterations, ...someData) {
   if (typeof iterations == "undefined") {
      iterations = 1;
   }
   var start = performance.now();
   for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      func.apply(this, someData);
   }

   var funcName = /function ([^\(]+)/.exec(func.toString())[0];
   v("Time to run " + funcName + " for " + iterations + " time(s): " + (performance.now() - start));
   return performance.now() - start;
}
```

A sample of how it is used (in this case, determining which of the 3 methods is faster to test if an element has a class assigned):

```
var e = document.getElementById("test");
timerTest(hasClass, 1000000, e, "x");
timerTest(hasClass2, 1000000, e, "x");
timerTest(hasClass3, 1000000, e, "x");

function hasClass(e, name) {
   if (typeof e !== "undefined" && typeof e.className !== "undefined") {
      return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + name + '(\\s|$)').test(e.className);
   }
   return false;
}

function hasClass2(e, name) {
   if (typeof e !== "undefined" && typeof e.className !== "undefined") {
      return (' ' + e.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + name + ' ') > -1;
   }
   return false;
}

function hasClass3(e, name) {
   if (typeof e !== "undefined" && typeof e.classList !== "undefined") {
      return e.classList.contains(name)
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Click the 9/15 to expand. "with strings, in function calls" is a no

Comment: It could be as simple as replacing `timerTest(func, iterations, ...someData)` with `function timerTest(func, iterations) {
  var someData = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2); ...}`.

Comment: @jeffcarey - Ah, I didn't notice that when I clicked on the 9/15 that it expanded. Thanks for pointing this feature out. This lets me know what options I have.

Comment: @robG - thanks for reminding me about the `arguments` keyword. That is a great and simple solution.

Comment: @mseifert—no worries. Oh, this is actually rest parameter syntax which is not supported in Safari 9 at all (according to Kangax's matrix). Careful with mobile too, support is patchy ([*according to MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#Browser_compatibility)).

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196) and it has nothing to do with "spread" in your case.

Comment: @FelixKling - What is the proper term for it then? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), "The spread syntax allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) ... are expected." and the example they give is `myFunction(...iterableObj);`

Comment: But you have a function *definition*, not a function *call*. As I mentioned in the post I linked to, the official name would be *rest parameter*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object

```
// call your timerTest function
timerTest(hasClass, 1000000, e, "x");
```

---

```
function timerTest(func, iterations) {

  if (typeof iterations == "undefined"){
     iterations = 1;
  }
  var start = performance.now();
  //Get parameters from arguments
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

  for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
    func.apply(this, args);
  }

  var funcName = /function ([^\(]+)/.exec(func.toString())[0];
  v("Time to run " + funcName + " for " + iterations + " time(s): " + (performance.now() - start));
    return performance.now() - start;
}
```

Comment: The function works with your changes, but when I compare the times it takes to run the functions shown in the example, your method takes between 67% and 10 times longer to run. The solution is to get the arguments into an array once using `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);` and then passing `args` with `func.apply(this, args);`

Comment: @mseifert Right, create the array inside the loop is not a good idea at all if you are measuring time, I guess I put the code before calling the function just for readability. I've just edited my answer.